# visual studio 2010 beta 1 slow? on 64bits/windows7

Tags: visual-studio

I have visual studios 10 beta installed on my windows 7 64bit laptop with 4gb and dual cores. I notice while developing ASP.NET app going to a page can be slow. After loading the first page it can take 3.5 seconds average to load the following pages. That shouldnt be. The same webapp on XP, 32bits, 512mb, single core visual studios 9 is fast enough for me not to notice the length of time. (both pcs are intel processors)

I wanted to know if i should switch back to MSVS 9? if theres an option i can change in my project? or OS to make it perform better or if theres anything i could do at all.

-edit-
msvs9 is faster but not as much. I wonder why performance is worse when this pc has better specs.

Comment: " wanted to know if i should switch back to MSVS 9"???  You should not have switched to 10.  It is for testing purposes and you are not allowed to deploy it into production as far as I understand the license.

Comment: Have you, for instance, defragmented your disks lately?

Comment: @john, its brand new. I havent touch the first 20gb and the OS+MSVS are large.

Answer (score 5):

You know it's a beta, right? They told you they weren't finished with it, didn't they?

More importantly, have you reported this to Microsoft at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualtudio? It sounds like you want it to be fixed, and this is the way to get it fixed.

Comment: Moreover, as described on http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/, they know performance sucks in the beta. Of course you should still report it on MS Connect to help them prioritize performance problems, but as far as beta1 goes, it's no surprise that it's slow.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is a beta remember.  Still might have some kinks to work out.

Just stick with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: VS2003 has always had the best performance for me, just a shame performance hasn't kept pace witht he later IDEs

Comment: Having fewer features, and an ASP.NET Design Mode too broken to use, really helped the performance of VS2003.